# PHP Array Elements as Arguments to SQL IN Operator

Tags: php, sql, arrays, select

```
$option_meno = ["Lukas", "Ivka"];
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM uctovnictvo 
        WHERE meno IN ('$option_meno[1]', '$option_meno[0]')
          AND datum BETWEEN '$date_start' AND '$date_end'
        ORDER BY $order ";
```

For sure there has to be a better way how to select user based on name (`meno`). There can be more or fewer names in the `$option_meno` array.

I would like to make especially this more simple than listing out each index in the option array `('$option_meno[1]','$option_meno[0]')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) :

```
$sql = " SELECT * 
         FROM uctovnictvo 
         WHERE meno IN ('" . implode('\', \'', $option_meno) . "') 
           AND datum BETWEEN '$date_start' AND '$date_end'  
         ORDER BY $order ";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use some array functions to auto generate the correct `IN` statement

```
$option_meno = ["Lukas","Ivka"];
$in = implode(',', array_map(function($item) use ($pdo) {
    return '"' . $pdo->quote($item) . '"';
}, $option_meno);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM uctovnictvo WHERE meno IN ($in)...";
```

instead of `PDO::quote` you could use also `mysqli_real_escape_string`, etc. (depends on your connection).